# angular search filter - unknown provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

main.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.factory('Avengers', function () {
  var Avengers = {};
  Avengers.cast = [
    {
      name: 'Darius',
      character: 'Darevicius'
    }

  ];
  return Avengers;
});

function AvengersCtrl($scope, Avengers) {
  $scope.avengers = Avengers;
}
```

index.html

```
<div ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>

<div ng-controller="AvengersCtrl">
     <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="actor in avengers.cast | searchText ">
        <td>{{ actor.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ actor.character }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

</div>
```

I get this error:

http://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector:unpr?p0=searchTextFilterProvider

and dont understand why it does not work. It is native angular filter and what dependency it needs? WHen I remover pipe character and filter, the list is printed and no errors. So it looks that it knows all dependencies.

This is by example from there:

http://www.thinkster.io/pick/ET1iee6rnm/angularjs-ngfilter

Comment: it should be filter:searchText not searchText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
<tr ng-repeat="actor in avengers.cast | filter:searchText ">
```

According to the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) you need to specify `filter:` before.

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
<tr ng-repeat="actor in avengers.cast | searchText ">
```

to

```
<tr ng-repeat="actor in avengers.cast | filter:searchText ">
```

Angular is attempting to look up a provider and apply it to the ng-repeat; since there's no searchTextProvider, this fails. There is, however, a filter provider.